# I'm having an issue with windows 10 boot times

Tags: windows, windows-10, motherboard, bios, infinite-loop

I'm having a problem with windows 10 boot times.

I usually had around 5-7 seconds boot (including bios time) but now it takes around 4 minutes while showing me the windows loading screen with the circle spinning.

This problem started today. 
Yesterday night before I closed the PC I wanted to do a restart because file manager kept crashing, but the restart was taking waaay too long so I just shut it down from the power button and went to sleep.

The next day (today) I opened it and it was fine, but at some point I wanted to watch a movie and vlc (media player) kept crashing so I shut it down and then tried to open it again. But it took way to long to load so I pressed the power button to shut it down again. I did this couple of times because I thought it was stuck in a loop and then an automatic repair appeared were it just showed me a black screen for like 5 minutes. After that I finally got into the setup and tried the repair startup option which  didn't succeed and asked me to restore it to a restore point which I tried and also didn't succeed.

So I thought I will let it load and maybe at some point it will boot and it actually did but it took around 4 minutes. I tried to shut it down and open it again to see if it's fixed but almost every time it does about 4 minutes.(some random times it opens quickly, but rarely). I tried booting from a usb (which at first was showing a blue screen for 5 minutes before it goes to the setup screen) and tried the windows repair which didn't work.

**Now it doesn't fully boot (stuck on loading screen) even after 15 minutes. Also I can't even fully boot from usb now (I just see a blue screen) even after 10-15 minutes.**
Could this be the motherboard that makes the problem?

Comment: For me it seems hard-disk issues! or missed files If S.M.A.R.T system didn't detect anything then give it a chance and make format, that's the only way that you can know if it's hardware or software issues.

Comment: It actually booted up after about an hour and I opened hard disk sentinel and saw that one of my hdd (not my sdd with the OS) is 51% health, so I'm guessing it has something to do with that. I will try unplug that drive and see what happens.

Comment: Don't throw your harddisk away sometimes a deep format or error fixer can solve the problem, maybe it's only bad partition, good luck..

Comment: Ok so I unpluged the faulty hdd and it worked fine. I will try to fix it and do a backup of my files. thanks :)

Comment: You might want to post an answer, rather than editing it into the question title or leaving it in the comments.

Comment: We appreciate your feedback, but we don't really put "**SOLVED**" in our subject titles.  As Journeyman Geek implied, we post answers, instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by a faulty hdd (not my main with the OS) who had some bad and weak sectors. Once I uplugged the sata 3 cable from the faulty hdd, everything was fine again with quick boots and no more chashes.